# Macbook Air 11" 2015 model A1465 not charging

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I installed a new SSD, formatted it, and Mojave OS was installing when suddenly, the battery stopped charging.  All I get now is a picture of a red battery with a low charge. If I remove the adapter, I get a picture that the adapter needs to be plugged in.  I tried different outlets. I tried a different adapter. I don't get a green light on the adapters. Reset SMC. Reset Pram.

So it needs a new DC-In board or battery (which apple says is not removable) or both?

Comment: So did the battery ever charge after re-assembly (update the question in case you cannot comment)? For deeply discharged batteries it may take quite some time for the first few percent to charge.

Comment: When I installed the new hard drive, the battery was really low.  I plugged in the computer, and it was a good connection, and the battery was slowly charging. I formatted the new drive and Mojave OS was installing.  I left it alone for maybe 30 minutes.  When I came back to check on the installation the battery was dead and the charger wasn't working. I tried a different charger and outlets.